# Reading Tab Separated Data In C99

Tags: c, file, input, io, c99

I can give my program input files such as the following:

```
1     0     0     0     2    -1
16    70  -169  -580    75
1     0     4     0    -5
0    -9     3     5    -3
5    -4     3    -2     0
1.0   -3.4    5.4531   -4.2077    1.5092   -0.2030
```

Each of these lines represents a polynomial.  For instance, the first line represents `x^6 + 2x^2 - 1`

I am trying to read in this file but am not sure how to deal with the tabs and new lines. I am also not sure how to handle the fact that the amount of coefficients and polynomials can change.

Right now I have:

```
polynomial** readPolyFile(FILE *polyFile){
    polynomial *p = NULL; 
    int size = 1; /* Size to malloc */
    polynomial **polynomials = NULL; 

    polyList = malloc(sizeof(polynomial*) * size); /* Initialize */

    if(polyList == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s %n: Could not allocate memory\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        exit(-99); 
    }

    /* Read all of the data from the file */
    do {

    }

}
```

My initial thought is to increment the size each time I need to, but I'm not sure if that's the best way to go about this.

My definition of `polynomial` is as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned int nterms;       /* number of terms */
    double complex *polyCoef;  /* coefficients    */
} polynomial;
```

I would like to return a list of polynomial structs. Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Comment: What is `complex` in your polynomial structure?

Comment: @MarekKlein I'm using a complex numbers library 
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/complex.h.html

Comment: @tibsar Note: Your sample coefficients do not contain any example of `complex`  numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Read inputs into a linked list and then form the array when done.

---

Some quick code, lacking needed error checking, to get you started.

Set up an empty linked-list

```
typedef struct LL {
  polynomial *poly;
  struct LL *next;
} LL;
LL head = { NULL, NULL };
LL *p = &head;
```

Inside the loop, read a line in the a buffer, parse it to a   `polynomial` and append to the LL.

```
#define N 1000
count = 0;
char buf[N];
/* Read all of the data from the file */
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, polyFile)) {
  p->next = malloc(sizeof *(p->next));
  p = p->next;

  // TBD code for OP.
  // Hint: degree of polynomial < sizeof buf/2
  p->poly = polyList_from_line(buffer);

  p->next = NULL;
  count++;
}
```

Allocate for the array

```
polyList = malloc(sizeof *polyList * count);
p = head.next;
for (i=0; i< count; i++) {
  assert(p);
  polylist[i] = p->poly;
  next = p->next;
  free(p);
  p = next;
}

return polylist;
```

---

Sub problem: More pseudo code to read tab separated data

```
  polynomial *polyList_from_line(char *buffer) {
    double complex coef[some factor of N];
    count = 0;

    char *token = strtok(buffer, "\t");
    while (token)  {
      // parse the token for a complex number
      if (sscanf(buffer, tbd_format, tbd_variables) != expected_result)
        break;
      coef[count++] = ...
      token = strtok(tbd_code);
    }
    // Malloc polynomial using count
    // Populate polynomial from coef[]
    // return allocation
  }
```